# How to uninstall a driver from OS X

Tags: macos, drivers, uninstall, modem, 3g

I have a 3G Modem, that i install on my mac, the first time it didn't want to work, i found out that i needed to update it (its firmware?) so as it works on my mac. That is what i did, and know it works. But when i have used it and try to shutdown my computer, it hangs, i have to force shutdown, just as if it can't "unmount" it or something.

I think it is may be due to my first usage (when it was not up to date) so i'd like to uninstall its driver from my mac and try again cleanly.

OS X 10.5
The 3G modem is an LG LDU 1900D